# Communication with BLE is not working, rarely it's working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
public void writeCharacteristic(byte[] speed_value){

    //check mBluetoothGatt is available
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "lost connection");
        return;
    }
    BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
    showMessage("new write char"+mBluetoothGatt);
    if (Service == null) {
        showMessage("service is null");
        broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
        Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
        return;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service.getCharacteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID);
    if (charac == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
        broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
        return;
    }

    charac.setValue(speed_value);
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
    Log.d(TAG, "writeRXCharacteristic: statux tx"+status);

}
```

Note : Some times it's working below API level 21 but here I try to run this over API level 21

Comment: Do you discover any service on the BLE device ? Are you able to connect to it ?

Comment: yes, connection established successfully. Only thing is have to do communication with BLE.

Comment: When it does not work on SDK below 21, do you enter onCharacteristicWrite() or onCharacteristicChanged() ? Can you check onConnectionStateChange() to see if the connexion is lost ?

Comment: yeah checked, its in connected state only.

Comment: What happens when you write on the characteristic using nRF Connect app ?